# How to create dragon like fire using particle effect in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, game-engine, effects, 2d-games, particle-system

I want to simulate a fire which seems same as dragon fire, which comes out of dragon mouth using libgdx Particle editor. It should go up in ashes once fire is completed (i guess on decay i will change color to black). I tried many things using particle editor and able to create a trail behind an ball, but want to make it a continuous fire (another example is flamethrower). Can someone help understand how to do it using Particle editor of libgdx? Do i need to create multiple emitter and place them at different places in same line?

Please help give some pointers which i can use to work in desired direction. Particle should start at a point(emitter) and then expand like fire.

Comment: as per my understanding of the question i think u have to make the particle continuous from particle editor itself

Comment: yes, but if dragon moves in different direction, fire will stay in same direction and this approach fails. I tried this, but fire is going in same direction even when dragon changes his face. I think we need to add multiple emitters, but not sure how.

Comment: a simple solution which i think is to make two emitter in two directions and use them.